# What purpose did the animals and people in cages serve for Skynet?

Tags: the-terminator-series, the-sarah-connor-chronicles

I have not seen this series for a while however I am reasonably confident the episode in question is "Allison from Palmdale", apologies if I am incorrect.

In one scene in the darkness of the future (or the world after the machines have taken over), the outside of what appears to be a docked large ship is shown. Either before or after that, we are shown a room inside the vessel containing cages of animals and if memory serves, humans as well.

The question is relatively simple: What was the purpose of Skynet collecting and keeping them? Was it likely for future study or is there more to this (either in- or out-of-universe)?

I could see why they might want human "specimens" for future study, but not immediately think why Skynet would also be interested in animals. Pretty sure the scene included both lions and monkeys, at least.

I did consider a "predator vs prey" study with animals by the machines but that in itself did not really seem fitting with any Skynet storyline.

Comment: Study, or repopulation, are the two most obvious answers.

Comment: "*Hunter-Killers: patrol machines built in automated factories. Most of us were rounded up, put in camps for orderly disposal. (pulls up his right sleeve, exposing a barcode) This is burned in by laser scan. Some of us were kept alive... to work... loading bodies. The disposal units ran night and day. We were that close to going out forever. But there was one man who taught us to fight, to storm the wire of the camps, to smash those metal motherfuckers into junk. He turned it around. He brought us back from the brink. His name is Connor. John Connor. Your son, Sarah, your unborn son.*"

Comment: But why put them in camps for orderly disposal, why no just blow them up, or killem all. If Skynet was worried about waste, dead humans would be great fertilizer for plants.

Comment: @AlessandroSanfilippo - The same reason the Nazis switched from bullets to gas, because it's more efficient

Comment: @Valorum It was more efficient for the Nazis because their officers kept getting traumatised by killing people and the gas was less psychologically damaging to them. That’s not an issue that the machines would have.

Comment: There was a documentary about that (Nazi gas vs gun) on tv here recently although I could not watch it :( Back on topic I well understand why Skynet would wish to retain human subjects for study etc but not really animal species. I do not think it was for repopulating as "the world" habitat was not suitable for wild animals at least far as is visible. I think I am just struggling for the machines reasoning for keeping animals aside from what I vaguely touched on before about a possible (animal vs animal not vs human!) "prey vs predator" study perhaps, but again I see no machine logic for that.

Comment: Clearly part of a new Terminator program to infiltrate monkey and lion communities.